# Getting error while feteching images from api

Tags: flutter, api

I am trying to fetch data from API but facing problems with the Network image.

// Error is
// 'error: The getter 'url' isn't defined for the type 'String'.

```
 // Future function     
     Future<ProductsModel> getPostApi() async {
        final response = await http.get(
            Uri.parse('https://webhook.site/cb3a5238-4695-470e-a00d-468dff4e638f'));
        var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          return ProductsModel.fromJson(data);
        } else {
          return ProductsModel.fromJson(data);
        }
      }
// future builder
            Expanded(

                              child: FutureBuilder<ProductsModel>(
                                  future: getPostApi(),
                                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                      return ListView.builder(
                                          itemCount: snapshot.data!.data!.length,
                                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                            return Column(
                                              children: [
                                                Container(
                                                  height:
                                                   MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .3,
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .1,
                                                  child: ListView.builder(
                                                    itemCount: snapshot
                                                        .data!.data![index].image!.length,
                                                    itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                                                      return Container(
                                                        height:
                                                         MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*.25,
                                                        width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *.5, 
        decoration: BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(
        // **here is the error in Url**
            image: NetworkImage(snapshot.data!.data![index].image![position].url),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      );
                                                    },
                                                  ),
                                                )
                                              ],
                                            );
                                          });
                                    } else {
                                      return constt Text('Loading');
                                    }
                                  })),
                        ],
```

Comment: please add the error message you are getting

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. You should state what error exactly you are getting and also what you have tried to do against it

Comment: @suzan check now

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to access the `url` as an object but the response is of type String.

You could do something like this

```
NetworkImage(snapshot.data!.data![index].image![position]['url'])
```

or

```
NetworkImage(snapshot.data!.data![index]['image'][position]['url'])
```